# How do I run cloc to check all python files of a directory including subdirectories but ignore any subdirectories that have the word migrations?

Tags: python, cloc

I installed cloc using brew.

I like to check number of lines of code for a Django project.

I definitely don't want to count those that inside migrations and only restrict to python files.

I tried `cloc --not-match-d=migrations --include-lang=python .` and `cloc --not-match-d=migrations --include-lang=py .`  at the project root, but they got ignored.

this is the result:

```
± cloc --not-match-d=migrations --include-lang=python .
   18714 text files.
   13100 unique files.
   18771 files ignored.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there... language name is case sensitive.  This should work

```
cloc --not-match-d=migrations --include-lang=Python .
```

The language name must match one of the entries of `cloc --show-lang`.  If there's a space in the name, wrap it in quotes, eg `--include-lang="Visual Basic"`.